# How to generate a class from an interface

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way in Visual Studio to right click an interface and 'Generate Class from Interface' so I end up with an empty class with all the properties and methods which the interface requires?

Kind of like Extract Interface, but backwards.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Not quite what you're asking for, but if you create a class, and declare it as implementing your interface, you can right click on the interface and select "Implement Interface."  This will add the appropriate methods to your class.

Comment: I found that in VS 2013, you have to right click on the interface name, not the class name.

Comment: In VS2015, you create an empty class which inherits the interface. Then you click on the interface name and hit "Ctl + ." (or click on the lightbulb to the left of the class name) and then select "Implement Interface" from that menu.

Comment: Any way to generate an interface that matches a class? E.g. implement class in an interface? I find myself making small updates and it's a nuisance to keep updating the interface manually

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer before was for C#, but if you are using VB.NET all you need to do is type in the **Implements IMyInterface** the line below the class declaration and press <Enter>.  It automatically generates *all* of the method and property signatures for you.  You can also always go back to the **Implements** line and press  again if any new methods or properties were added to the Interface and they too will be generated for you.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically address this question, yes, there is.  Caveat, I'm using C#, working with the Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Edition.

Create an empty class, like "Class1":

```
class Class1
{
}
```

Then append an interface name, such as IObjectBase (which I'll continue to use for the remainder of this post), by using the ":", as in the following example:

```
class Class1:IObjectBase
```

When you do, there will be a short, thick, white underline, under the first letter of your interface name "I".  Mouse-over it.  There are a number of options which may appear.  You're looking for a small icon which looks like a page with a dog-eared, top-right corner as you hover over the small, thick white line, with the tooltip of "Options to implement interface".  Click on the drop-down arrow to its right.

You'll be presented with two menu item options: "Implement interface 'IObjectBase'" and "Explicitly implement interface 'IObjectBase'".  From there the choice is yours.

If you're looking for guidance regarding the two options, I'd suggest reading the following articles, I think each covers the topic well, yet from different viewpoints:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/392516/Why-I-use-explicit-interface-implementation-as-a-d
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136319/whats-the-difference-between-implementing-an-interface-explicitly-or-implicitly

Regards,

HALAR